# How to download multiple videos in background in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin iOS, i need to download multiple videos at same time. how should i achieve this ? is there any class which can help me download similar to the DownloadManager in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approaches

```
public void getData(List<String> urls) {
    // define the HttpClient
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect=false };
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    // define file path
    var path=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    // start download
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(urls, async (url) => {
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

        // download the file
        var data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);

        // save file on disk
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName), data);
    });
}
```

Comment: will this approach run in background ? and what happens if the app is closed ?

Comment: i'm not sure but if you register you app to run in background it is possible. see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/registering_applications_to_run_in_background/